# How to monitor Windows Server disk I/O Hard Drive stats

Tags: hard-drive, monitoring, windows-server-2012

I would like to know the maximum speed that my hard drive could run, and the percentage of it's performance whether it's working too much until it reach the limit or still have a lot of iddle time. How can I check it on Windows Server 2012.

For example, say I uses some tools and the tools say I am using 5 MB/s

I want to know whether 5MB/s means too much IO or not. Should I upgrade to SSD.

I have no idea what's the maximum capability of the hard disk. Is it 5MB/s? Is it 100MB/s

What tools should I use to know that.

I am using windows.

Answer (score 0):

I've used PassMark PerformanceTest for Windows Servers, they have a 30day free trial. It will tell you the capacities of your hard drives as well as other hardware components.

http://www.passmark.com/products/pt.htm